# Raspberry Pi 1 with Adafruit PiTFT - 2.8 - No module named 'bitmaptools'

Tags: adafruit, pi-1

I installed the screen with:

https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi.pdf

I have been trying to run adafruit_blinka_pyportal_nasa.py from:

https://learn.adafruit.com/running-pyportal-code-on-blinka-with-displayio/running-examples

Which gives me the *error*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adafruit_blinka_pyportal_nasa.py", line 12, in <module>
    from adafruit_pyportal import PyPortal
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adafruit_pyportal/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from adafruit_portalbase import PortalBase
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adafruit_portalbase/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from adafruit_display_text.bitmap_label import Label
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adafruit_display_text/bitmap_label.py", line 30, in <module>
    import bitmaptools
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitmaptools'
```

I have looked in bitmap_label.py and tried to change it with the help of:

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Display_Text/blob/main/adafruit_display_text/bitmap_label.py

But it still does not work.

Also https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/bitmaptools/index.html does not give me any answers.

Comment: In case this is helpful to someone: I'm getting this as well, attempting to do `from adafruit_magtag.magtag import MagTag` or even just `from adafruit_portalbase import PortalBase` on something other than a MagTag (namely, a GNU/Linux desktop machine, not a Raspberry Pi either), _in hopes_ of of finding a way to use the same libraries to generate an image similar to what I want displayed on the screen, to be able to test some code in a different environment.  If I find a solution, I'll post an answer.